# How to get flask abort code from within after_request function?

Tags: flask

I have a problem and after a few hours of searching I can't find a solution.

I have a flask based API. Under normal flow it works like this:

- `before_request` handler is used to validate things like the customer and their API key etc.
- Then the requested endpoint function is called
- I then use `after_request` to log various stats about the API call

That all works great.

The problem is when I need to call abort during the before_request. For example, `abort(404)`
In this situation, the User receives the abort status error code (404) and the execution continues to the after_request handler (as expected)

My issue is that I cant work out how to "know", from within the `after_request` handler, that the request has been aborted.

Within the `after_request` function the `response` object has a status_code of 200, not 404 - I assume because the endpoint was never called and 200 is its default setting.

I either need the response object to reflect the actual code that was returned to the end-user or have some way of knowing that the abort/exception occurred.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
I had forgotten to return the error code as part of my custom error handler.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing different result than you are:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort

def create_app(config_file=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.debug = True

    @app.before_request
    def before_request():
        print("Before request: pre 404")
        abort(404)
        print("Aborts before getting to this")

    @app.after_request
    def after_request(request):
        print("After request: pre")
        print(request.status_code)  # <-- this is 404
        print("After request: post")

        return request

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return "This string never makes it screen"

    return app
```

```
Before request: pre 404
After request: pre
404
After request: post
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2021 15:01:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

What is your setup and what is the result for what you are seeing with comparable code?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Doug Miller. If I run your code I get the same result as you.
I am using a blueprint and I'm using @bp.app_errorhandler(xxx) for my error handling. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Actually I just found the problem! My mistake